# WebJars in playframework - react.js and play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playframework, webjars

Are you using webjars with playframework?
Am I using them wrong? Can someone point me to guide how to use them?

I have currently this in head:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/i18n.js")'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.fullPath("react","react.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("react","react-dom.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("bootstrap.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.fullPath("react-i18next","react-i18next.js"))'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("react-router.js"))'></script>
```

, which looks bad , but I am just starting to learn react. I created my first component and when I want to use it I can not import them, I have to put  path to component in script tag ... and when I will have 20-30 components , how many of this tags will I have to have?

Is there any way I can make import work with webjars?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are at: http://www.webjars.org/documentation

For a better loading experience you can use RequireJS which is supported by WebJars.  The docs contain info on how to use RequireJS with Play.